# update variable with using function

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a some kind of jumping game with functions,loop and if else.my problem is,i can't save the location of character.Like i want to update location after every move(right,left,reverse).how can i write as a function ?

```
x=0
y=0
last=[x,y]
a=[1,2]
#1=turn_left 2=turn_right
def move(last):
    for i in a:
        if i==1:
            last=[x+2,y+3]
            return last
        if i==2:
            last=[x-1,y+1]
            return last
        
move(last)
```

for example, in this code it's printing [2,3] but 1 and 2 are in the a.shouldn't it print as [1,4] why didn't last variable update?

Comment: The variable `last` inside the function is not the same variable as the `last` outside the function.  You need to write `last = move(last)` so the value returned by your function gets assigned to your outside-the-function variable

Comment: If you use a global variable to store the position, you even do not need any return clause and the `last` as input argument.

Answer (score 1):

Using return terminates the function. Your code only executes the first element of 'list a' and exits immediately. Also, since the values ​​of x and y are fixed to 0, when the second element of a comes in, 'list last' will be [-1,1].

```
def move(last):
    for i in a:
        if i==1:
            last[0] += 2
            last[1] += 3
        elif i==2:
            last[0] -= 1
            last[1] += 1
    return last
```

- When determining the value of i, using elif can save resources.